# Discord bot can´t kick with admin privileges

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.py

I am trying to build a bot using discord.py. Everytime I try to kick, it returns this exception:

```
FORBIDDEN (status code: 403): Privilege is too low..
```

However, it can kick members, who don´t have a role assigned to them. The bot has admin privileges, so I think it should be able to do anything.

Where do I give the bot the privileges to kick?

Comment: Could you add a link to your code? If you do, **make sure to remove your token**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go into server settings >roles

Make sure that you drag whatever role the bot has above any other roles you want him to be able to manipulate. Roles with admin privileges can only affect members with roles below them in the hierarchy. This is what prevents a moderator with the manage roles permission from being able to remove Admins from their roles.